# Insert Into sql default value error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, default-value, insert-into

I am trying to insert values into my database via java but I keep getting a "doesn't have a default value" error message. I have looked online to find some help but they haven't really solved my problem. This is the error that I am getting "java.sql.SQLException: Field 'firstName' doesn't have a default value".

```
import java.sql.*;

class MysqlCon {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String personalID = null;
    String firstname = null;
    String lastname = null;
    String addressone = null;
    String addresstwo = null;
    String city = null;
    String state = null;
    String zipcode = null;
    String phone = null;
    String email = null;

    try
    {

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Address_Book","root","");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

personalID ="3";
firstname = "John";
lastname = "Doe";
addressone = "4000 s.c.r. 222";
addresstwo = "5000 n.c.r. 333";
city = "place";
state = "Texas";
zipcode = "43523";
phone = "43523524";
email = "weqtatw@aadf.com";

stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Names(personID) values("+personalID+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Names(firstname) values("+firstname+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Names(lastname) values("+lastname+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into addresses(address1) values("+addressone+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into addresses(address2) values("+addresstwo+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into addresses(city) values("+city+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into addresses(state) values("+state+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into addresses(zipcode) values("+zipcode+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into phoneNumbers(phoneNumber) values("+phone+")");
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into emailAddresses(emailAddress) values("+email+")");
con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: You need to specify all the columns in one statement: `INSERT INTO Names (personID, firstname, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)`

Comment: I have add the error message that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently running three separate insert statements into one table, such as:

```
INSERT INTO Names (personID) values (3);
INSERT INTO Names (firstname) values ("John");
INSERT INTO Names (lastname) values ("Doe");
```

You will end up with 3 separate rows, instead of a single row.  If any of the columns require a value (i.e. if you have a primary key without an auto_increment), the insert will fail since it will require a value for the column (edit: in this case you have a required value for the firstName field).

You'll also have a very useless table that will contain entries such as a row with nothing but the name "John", a row with nothing but the last name "Doe", and a row with personID of 3.

Instead, you should be running a single INSERT statement, such as:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Names(personID, firstname, lastname) values("+personalID+", "+firstname+", "+lastname+")");
```

Which should also populate all required cells in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run one of `insert into` commands in database shell first - you will see that command like `insert into Names(personID) values(3)` is not correct because DB does not know what to insert into other fields. However, it would know if there is a default value for missing fields - that's why DB is complaining.

If you do not have default values for that table (they are set up while table creation), you must give all values at once like this:

`INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`